# Products - Add to cart

Tags: nodes, commerce, rules, emails

I need some advice.

My client has a website with loads of products.  Now the client want the ability to add products to a cart, and instead of buying, they want the products to be mailed.

How can I acheive this.  I took a look at the [commerce module](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce).  This module is amazing.  I did some research and found [this article](https://drupalcommerce.org/node/803) saying I can achieve  what I want with the [rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.

This is awesome.  But drupal commerce has its own set op products that you need to add inside the store.  I need to use products already created. As well as add options such as colors and sizes that also needs to be displayed in Select lists.

Is there a way that I can get this feature with existing products? Or just add the cart button to my nodes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how your node 'products' are setup. In Drupal Commerce, 'products' are a fieldable Entity Type and each bundle of that entity type is a different product with different sets of fields.

One possible solution would be to check out the [Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) and its [ecosystem of other modules](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_extras) to see if there would be a way to convert your product Content Type to a Product Type.

Note that in the native Commerce workflow, you also need a Product Display node to act as a container for products to display them to the end user. Think of the Product entity as a single product option [in the example of a t-shirt it could be "X-Large Blue"] and the Product Display node is the wrapper that contains all options to display as a single "product" to the user.

Comment: Awesome! thanks for the answer.  I will definitely investigate... Will let know what my discovery is